# How to set timer on worker role?

Tags: azure

How to create a Worker role in Azure using timer?

Answer (score 4):

If you create a new worker role, the template code generates a Run() method for you. In that Run() method, you'll see the easiest way to create a timer:

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Trace.WriteLine("Working", "Information");
}
```

So in this example, the thread sleeps for 10 seconds, then wakes up and emits a log statement. You can change the time interval to be anything you want, and you then call whatever custom code you have after Thread.Sleep() returns.